# password encryption for use by aws automated process

Tags: amazon-web-services, password-encryption

I have an application that creates automatically some AWS instances and runs a script on them.

Each script tries to connect to a remote DB for which I need to provide the Public DNS Hostname, DB password, DB Username, etc...

What is the most secure way to do that without having to store the plain password?

And without risking somebody else running the same script being able to get those credentials?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [AWS SSM service's Parameter Store](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html):

> Parameter Store centralizes the management of configuration data -
>   such as passwords, license keys, or database connection strings - that
>   you commonly reference in scripts, commands, or other automation and
>   configuration workflows. With granular security controls for managing
>   user access and strong encryption for sensitive data such as
>   passwords, Parameter Store improves the overall security posture of
>   your managed instances. Encrypting parameters with Parameter Store is
>   not supported in all regions.

You would create an IAM role that has access to the Parameter Store values, and assigned that role to the EC2 instances you are dynamically creating. Then the script would be able to use the AWS SDK/CLI to retrieve those values from the parameter store.

---

Alternatively, if the database is an RDS database [that supports IAM authentication](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/04/manage-access-to-your-rds-for-mysql-and-amazon-aurora-databases-using-aws-iam/) (only MySQL and Aurora at this time) then you could create an IAM role that has direct access to the database and assign that role to the EC2 instances.